# how to find in ionic project (<android>/<app>/build.gradle)

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, gradle

I'm trying to add Firebase to my android app builded with ionic, the firebase's documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup says to add this line on my root-level build.gradle.

Here's my Project-level build.gradle (/build.gradle):

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    // Add this line
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
 }
}
```

App-level build.gradle (//build.gradle):

```
dependencies {
  // Add this line
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
}
...
// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: please, reference to 
`https://grokonez.com/ionic/ionic-3-firebase-integrate-firebase-in-ionic-3-project-with-angularfire2`
`https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase/`.

Comment: I want the Project-level build.gradle (<project>/build.gradle):

 and App-level build.gradle (<project>/<app-module>/build.gradle):

there is no information about them

Answer (score 2):

You can find both gradle files in platforms folder,

**Project-level build.gradle (/build.gradle)**: At platforms/android/build.gradle

**App-level build.gradle (//build.gradle)**: At platforms/android/app/build.gradle